# Looking for Group in RPG-deprived cities

Tags: new-players, group-dynamics

I live in Santiago de Chile. RPG resources here are -to my knowledge- few and far between. AFAIK there's one single shop selling RPG dice, the rest of the bookstores having dwindled and waned their RPG books/accessories supplies.

I do have a group with which we are playing a 2E Dragonlance mini campaign. This has been my first tabletop RPG experience, and I liked it a lot. The problems are:

- the DM is already playing other very advanced campaigns, so he doesn't have much time to start a new one, and the campaigns he runs or plays wouldn't easy for me to join.
- On this 2E campaign we are a very large group, 7 players + DM, so we have had a long stretch of not playing because we couldn't get all together, and since it is the first time many of us play, and it's a short campaign, missing one session would be very detrimental to the player.

I won't ask "What would be the best way to approach the DM about playing in one of his other groups?" because I've already checked other similar questions here, like "[Best practices to auditioning a new player](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4049/932)". Plus, if the session goes well and the DM likes my roleplaying, we'll probably agree on something.

Have you been in the same situation? What would your suggestions be on how to find a group?
If you actually live in the area, let's get together and play! I'd like to do a 4E campaign, but certainly beggars can't be choosers.

**EDIT** I added [a separate question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4282/932) to deal with 'how do I host a playing session when I have no space at home?'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find other RPG players?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players)

Comment: This does seem like a mishmash of old questions and new. In terms of "finding new people to make a group," I would suggest the question Jeremiah linked to, in fact I get three hits near Santiago using nearbygamers.com using one of the tools suggested there.  But it sounds like you also have "How to find a place to game" and "How to leverage an existing group of gamers to start a new game" problems.  Suggest posting those clearly and separately, because responding back-and-forth with freeform advice is not really supported by the format.

Comment: You're completely right.

Comment: Cool, and this inspired me to go add a big answer of my own and upvote the "finding gamers" question - it came up in the very beginning of the site so didn't get as much love as it should have.

Comment: This is really borderlining on a "Looking for Group in [x location]" type question, which does not fit within the scope of this site.  I strongly suggest this be rephrased, to remove any details of a specific location or requests for other locals to join.  On second thought, if we pull that out then we're left with "Where can I find other RPG players?" which would - as Jeremiah pointed out - be a duplicate.

Comment: Since you've posted a [clearer version](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4282) of one of the questions (which is good btw!) and "How to find a game in my city?" is off topic by the [faq](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq) so I'm voting to close this one as too localized.

Comment: @yhw42, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three recommendations.

The first: seek online games. They offer different, but still quite viable roleplaying opportunities, and you can find them in every possible game flavour.

Second: Run your own game. We'd be happy to find you a game that fits your requirements, and it sounds like your current group is too large for logistics. Ask some of them to join you while you experiment with a different game (I recommend a completely different genre to reduce the "well the OLD gm was better" syndrome.)

Third: Find local game days at your FLGS (friendly local game store). Wizards sponsors game days and it may be possible to find other people looking for a game there.