# How to become a good RPG player

Tags: new-players, social

I have never played a pen and paper RPG before due to social pressures, and none of my friends have ever voiced interest in doing so until recently. Usually most people I know look down on RPG playing which is part of the reason I've never looked into it. However now I have begun to look into playing despite knowing anyone else who does.

Recently a new friend mentioned running a DnD campaign this summer, and I'm interested in joining.

1. [<strike>Is there some sort of etiquette that goes into being a good player?</strike>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36993/player-etiquette)
2. [<strike>How can I make things easier for the GM?</strike>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36994/how-to-make-the-gms-job-easier)
3. [<strike>How do I go about making a good character?</strike>](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Interesting-Back-Story-for-Your-RPG-Character)
4. [<strike>I just want to have fun and unleash my imagination, but I have no idea on what expectations to have for an RPG.</strike>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15689/how-much-plot-guidance-is-too-much)
5. [<strike>Are there any signs of a good group/GM that I should be aware of?</strike>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25484/how-can-i-screen-new-players-to-make-sure-they-are-a-good-fit-for-my-game)

EDIT: All questions have been answered.

Comment: Welcome, Solidus. There are way too many questions in this question. And many of the others have already been answered. Search, show some research, and ask, as separate questions, the ones that are left. It's also worth mentioning, after having done research, *which* D&D edition you're planning on playing.

Comment: This site is not a forum, You should check out the the [FAQ], [ask], and [What is on-topic](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also, once you get 20 reputation you can join us in the [RPG General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat).

Comment: You need to split all these questions into separate questions.

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance! I look forward to reading the expanded questions, they look great.

Comment: We have an existing question that covers your #4 as well: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/im-at-a-loss-with-dungeons-and-dragons-how-does-one-play-it-anyway . Kudos for wanting to be prepared. :)

Comment: I thought the original question #9 ("How attached should I be to the character I make?") (which disappeared around revision 5) was a really interesting new-player question that I don't remember seeing addressed here and also quite a bit different from making an interesting character. But if you've eked out an answer, that's cool.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I haven't found an answer yet so I've posted it as a [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37024/how-attached-should-players-be-to-the-characters-they-make) if you want to take a shot at answering it.